# Sync phpMyAdmin DB's Across Desktops

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cloud

So i just setup my Xampp Apache server to load all the documents i create on my Google Drive. For example if i type 127.0.0.1, it will show me all my web files on my Google Drive. I set this up so i can develop across my laptop which i use at school and my desktop which i use at home without having to copy files back and forth between computer to computer. This works the way i want it to but i forgot one thing. How am i supposed to sync my databases that i create. My question to you is how can i sync my databases to the cloud or somewhere else so i don't have to export and import every time i switch devices?

Also i would like to stay away from using hosting as i won't be online all the time.

Comment: I presume Google Drive keeps the master copy of all your documents. If you are going to do this with a database, you need to decide which version is the "master". You would make all your changes on the master version and copy those changes to your "copies"

Answer (score 0):

The database server (the application itself) expects exclusive access to the data files. If you try to synchronize a data file between two systems, you're going to have issues and probably data loss.

What you could do is synchronize the data directory and make sure you're only running one server at a time. So when you're done working on the laptop, shut down the MySQL server process/service (mysqld), wait for it to finish synchronizing, and then start up the mysqld on the desktop. I suspect this will work, but it's a pretty non-standard usage so anything could happen.

To make it easier, I'd definitely consider writing a wrapper script/batch file that first tests for the presence of a lock file, then (if non exists) creates one, starts the mysqld, and when exiting make sure mysqld is stopped before deleting the lock file.

Anyway, to make this happen you would first stop mysqld everywhere, take the one mysql data directory that you wish to use, copy it to your Google Drive, then edit all of your MySQL configuration files to point to the new data directory instead of the old one. Whether XAMPP makes this more difficult than it should be, I'm not sure, but with stock MySQL it should be pretty trivial.

Remember that just because it's possible doesn't make it a good idea, and likewise that just because it's not a good idea doesn't make it won't work. So I'm saying it's not a good idea to do this, but if done with proper attention it will "probably" work.

Hope that helps.